# Filter based on array in multiple documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using Python and I have the following data:

```
    [
        {
                "_id" : "owner-12567c18-9f6a-49d0-a0d7-4b5d4634a46f",
                "car-e2a17cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67" : [
                        15,
                        0,
                        0,
                        false
                ],
                "car-e2a27cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67" : [
                        32,
                        0,
                        0,
                        true
                ]
        },
        {
            "_id":'owner-xxx',
           'car_y': [
                x,
                x,
                x,
                false
            ]
         }
    ]
```

It follows the schema _id of an owner,then an entry for every car and a list containing 4 fields.

I would like to filter for every car of an owner the one that the last element is false, so only the car **car-e2a17cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67** would be returned.

Comment: you have dynamic changing key? O.o

Comment: @varman The key is the '_id', a car owner, who then has different cars with also unique identifiers. For every car of an owner, there is a list I would like to filter based on the last element

Comment: So you have have a key like `cars : {name:"car-e2a.....",entry:[15,0,false]}` . Something like this.  I dont know how to identify dynamically changing key.

Comment: @varman This is directly copied from my mongo shell... I have a dictionary with a unique key'_id' that represents a person as value , then at the same "level" comes the car that holds an id as key and a list as value

Comment: We can find a key by value on programs, but i dont think we can find a key by value mongo. Maybe someone helps you

Comment: @varman maybe I didn't explain myself well, but I am sure you can filter keys based on array values in mongo, thanks for the help regardless!

Comment: i'm looking forward

Answer (score 1):

I think You do need qoutas to get JSON structure - is it the case of data provider?

After it You'll get dictionary structure:

```
d = [
    {
        "_id" : "owner-12567c18-9f6a-49d0-a0d7-4b5d4634a46f",
        "car-e2a17cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67" : ["15", "0", "0", "false"],
        "car-e2a27cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67" : ["32", "0", "0", "true"]
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : "owner-2",
        "car-e2a17cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67" : ["15", "0", "0", "false"],
        "car-e2a27cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67" : ["32", "0", "0", "true"],
        "car-special" : ["32", "0", "0", "false"]
    }
    ]

for owner in d:    
    for key in owner.keys():
        if (owner[key][3] == "false"):
            print('owner: ', owner['_id'], '| car: ', key)

#output:
#owner:  owner-12567c18-9f6a-49d0-a0d7-4b5d4634a46f | car:  car-e2a17cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67
#owner:  owner-2 | car:  car-e2a17cdb-3c13-44ad-af66-d9cd31cdbf67
#owner:  owner-2 | car:  car-special
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I would like to avoid processing data after querying it, instead, retrieving it directly from the mongo database!